# Ajax replace method does not working error

Tags: ajax, callback

Ajax replace method doesn't working in these code.But append method is working.

```
<?php    
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");
$currentTime = date("Y-m-d");
global $user;

 function form_test_permission()
 {
 return array(
      'submit_form_test' =>array(
      'title' =>t('Submit_form_test'),
      'description' => t('Submit the form_test form'),
),
);
}


  function form_test_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['production'] = array(
        'title' =>'Production',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'access arguments' => array('submit_form_test'),
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('form_test_form'),

    );

  return $items;
}

function form_test_form($form,&$form_state) {
  $form['production'] = array(
    '#title' => t('production'),
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value'=> '1',
    );
    $form['production1'] = array(
    '#title' => t('production1'),
    '#type' => 'hidden',

    );

    $form['production_date'] = array(
    '#title' => t('production_date'),
    '#type' => 'hidden',
     '#value' => date('Y-m-d'),
    );
    $form['production_time'] = array(
    '#title' => t('production_time'),
    '#type' => 'hidden',
     '#value' => date('H:i:s'),
    );
    $form['production23'] = array(
    '#title' => t('production23'),
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value'=> '1',
    );


   $form['button2'] = array(
    '#value' => 'UNDO',
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#prefix' => '<div  class="test">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#submit' => array('form_test_form_button2'),


    );

  $form['button1'] = array(
    '#value' => '  ADD  ',
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#prefix' => '<div  class="test1">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#submit' => array('form_test_form_button1'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_example_submit_driven_callback',
        'method' => 'replace',    
        'effect' => 'fade',
        'event' =>'click',
        'wrapper' => 'countvalue',


    ),

    );

    $form['start_counter'] = array(

    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array (
        'Start' => 'Start',
      '2501 ' => '2501 ',
      '302 ' => '302 ',
      '1107 ' => '1107', 
      '1104' => '1104',
      '0106' => '0106',
      '0305' => '0305',
      '0103' => '0103',
    ),
    '#prefix' => ' <div class="box chart gradient" style="width:30%;float:left;margin-top: -186px;">

                            <div class="title">

                                <h4>

                                    <span style="text-align:center;">Downtime</span>
                                </h4>

                            </div>
                            <div class="content" style="padding-bottom:0;">
                              <p class="dowtime-show" id="counter"></p>',

   );
   $form['start_counter1'] = array(

    '#type' => 'textfield',


   );
    $form['stop_counter'] = array(

    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array (
    'Stop'=>'Stop',
      'Mechanical' => 'Mechanical',
      'Electrical' => 'Electrical',
      'Programming' => 'Programming', 
      'Setup' => 'Setup',
      'PlannedMaintenance' => 'PlannedMaintenance'
    ),
 '#suffix' => '</div> </div>',

   );
   $form['counter'] = array(

    '#type' => 'textfield',

    );

       $form['button3'] = array(
    '#value' => 'submit',
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#submit' => array('form_test_form_button3'),


    );
  return $form;
}

function ajax_example_submit_driven_callback($form,$form_state){


 $result = db_query("SELECT * FROM  form_test WHERE production_date='2014-02-10' and production_time between '01:00:00' and '02:00:00'");
    $prod_1= $result->rowcount();
    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
     $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    return 'count value is:'.$prod_1.'';

}   



function form_test_form_button1($form,&$form_state){

    $ft_id = db_insert('form_test')
    ->fields(array(
    'production' => $form_state['values']['production'],
    'production_date' => $form_state['values']['production_date'],
    'production_time' => $form_state['values']['production_time'],
    'production1' => $form_state['values']['production1'],

    ))
    ->execute();
     $form_state['rebuild'] = true;

    }

function form_test_form_button2($form,&$form_state){

    $ft_id = db_insert('form_test1')
    ->fields(array(
    'production23' => $form_state['values']['production23'],
    'production_date' => $form_state['values']['production_date'],
    'production_time' => $form_state['values']['production_time'],
    ))
    ->execute();
    }

function form_test_form_button3($form,&$form_state){

    $ft_id = db_insert('downtime1')
    ->fields(array(
    'start_counter1' => $form_state['values']['start_counter1'],
    'stop_counter' => $form_state['values']['stop_counter'],
    'counter' => $form_state['values']['counter'],
    'production_date' => $form_state['values']['production_date'],
    'production_time' => $form_state['values']['production_time'],
    ))
    ->execute();
    }
```

I spend a lot of hours to get the result but cannot able to get it.Anybody know how to solve these kind of Errors.The main problem is that it doesn't change the value while using replace method.

Comment: On line 12 it seems to be an extra/incorrect parenthethis, other than that you would have to provide more information what you are trying to achieve and what the problem is